# Why lightbox doesn't work when div has a child div

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I'm using a lightbox plugin the uses rel="lightbox" to fire the lightbox in a gallery I'm creating using the Advanced Custom Fields pluin. All works great until I want to add a child div that is absolutely positioned in the box div. It's supposed to change opacity on hover and still have the lightbox fire.

My markup

```
  <?php if(get_field('image')):
    $attachment_id = get_field('image');
    $size = "full";
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); 
    $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
    $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" rel="lightbox"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, medium); ?>  </a>
      <div class="hover-title">
    <?php  the_field('hover_title');?>
    </div><!-- hover title -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- box -->
```

If I simply remove the "hover-title" lightbox works. But I want to use that :)

my css:
    .box a {
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    }

Answer (score 0):

is that the full code. if so then you are missing an opening `<div>`.

fyi your first two lines should read

```
$attachment_id = get_field('image');
if ( $attachment_id ) {

}
```

no need to call get_field() twice, it is a database call after all.

Good Luck